# How to keep job search secret if your company's tool is used in hiring?

Tags: job-search, secrecy

Assuming I work for a company whose product is sometimes used in hiring (think ATS or SaaS or similar), how can I keep my job search a secret? I wouldn't want my name showing up internally if someone happened to stumble across it or search for it, but I also am not sure a new company would be comfortable with me using an alias.

Current company is one where I'm not sure if any new company I'm applying at uses it, but I do know I'd like to keep my search a secret. I wouldn't be competing with my current company if I joined another one, but the new company may be using our services.

Comment: Do you really think that ssome massive company with massive tool has search alert for your name entering its database, ignoring all privacy violations this would cause?

Comment: I'm less worried about an active search than someone just stumbling upon my name. I'd like to minimize the risk.

Comment: So you worry that random person in this big company will run into someone with your name on the system, will also know you, and then actually assume it's you, dig in, and then act on it to tattle to the bosses that you are maybe job hunting... Or maybe it's just your old cv foating around? Play lottery on the day that happens, because you are trying to protect from an improbable as heck angle.

Comment: My current company is not enterprise-sized.

Comment: Do you know how many users are currently in the database? Do you know how often, if ever, employees look at production data?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

> Assuming I work for a company whose product is sometimes used in hiring (think ATS or SaaS or similar), how can I keep my job search a secret?

Assuming that your company has privacy policies, client data is kept private, ethical guidelines etc., then you need not to worry.

If your info (current or old) would happen to be in the system, someone else on your company looking it up, disclosing etc would be a privacy violation of your rights, and I bet also a violation of company policies and client data privacy... and in the case there weren't privacy policies, ethical guidelines etc., then that would be more of a red-flag and even more reason for you to job-hunt.

Thus, I think this is a non-problem. Just continue job-hunting and doing your job in the meantime.

Comment: While I don't think it's a non-issue... I agree that there's likely not much I can do, so I've accepted this answer. Thank you

Comment: Glad it helped @User938232 and precisely, *you* may think it's an issue/problem, but personally I and 11 other people (at the time of writing this) seem to think that it's not and that you should not worry about that. Good luck :)

Answer (score -4):

**Apply with a nickname/alternate name**

I have a full name, the only person that calls me that is my Mum when she's angry at me or a Judge - otherwise, I prefer to go by a common shortened version of it.

Alternatively, you could apply with a Middle Name or as is common practice for people who aren't from the Anglosphere - you could apply with an Anglicised version of your name (if applicable)

Enough that when the details are entered, the first name that someone 'Might stumble across' is different enough from what they know you as so as to not alert anyone.

Examples include - going by Bill instead of William or Dick instead of Richard.

Comment: OP did mention: *"but I also am not sure a new company would be comfortable with me using an alias."* - just wanted to comment in case you missed it (in case not, your answer can be taken as "dont worry about that, go for an alias")

Comment: What implications could there be and what suggestions can you give regarding Background Checks and OP not using their legal, official name (the one on your social security, on your past job records etc).

Comment: @DarkCygnus - I see an Alias differently to what I suggested - An Alias is more a False name (to me) whereas anglicized names or contractions or middle names are within the realm of 'standard conventions' IMO. in terms of Background checks - when you get to that point in the hiring process - then it might be an idea to say give the legal name and let them know you applied with a variation due to the business relationship.